# SQL insertion with two errors

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a transaction in my MMSQL database with Javascript.
I have tried this command which inserts some elements to a table myTable:

```
const  sql = require('mssql');

const  sqlConfig = {
  user: 'xxx',
  password: 'xxx',
  server: 'xxx',
  database: 'myDatabase',
  options: {
    encrypt: false
  }
};

const result = await connection.query("INSERT INTO [myTable] ([ID],[ClassId],[Active],[LastUpdateDateTime] ,
                                                             [LastUpdateUser] ,[Number] ,[ExternalId] ,
                                                             [MaterialDefinitionId] ,[CompanyId] ,[IsBlanket] ,
                                                             [Type] ,[Subtype] ,[CreatedDate] ,[ValidFromDate] ,
                                                             [ValidToDate] ,[OrderedQuantity] ,[DeliveredQuantity] ,
                                                             [ReservedQuantity] ,[UnitOfMeasurement] ,[Status],
                                                             [Note],[RowVer]) 
                                                             VALUES ('0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0',
                                                             '0','0','0','0','0','0','0')");
```

But i get this timestamp error:

**RequestError: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.**

So i removed all the probably time dependent elements (LastUpdateDateTime , CreatedDate , ValidFromDate , ValidToDate).

But i still get a new error:

**RequestError: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_MaterialLot_Company". The conflict occurred in database "myDatabase", table "myTable", column 'ID'.**

So i'm a bit lost here. Does someone have an idea about the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `timestamp` has nothing to do with a DateTime. It is a database generated value that changes with every update /insert and is used for versioning. In the case above the likely culprit is the column `RowVer` (based on the name). You cannot define the value for that column so it needs to be removed from the statement completely.

Comment: On the second error you are trying to insert a value on a column that has a FK constraint because it's value is linked to another table. Your value is one that does not exist in this other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> RequestError: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_MaterialLot_Company". The conflict occurred in database
>   "myDatabase", table "myTable", column 'ID'.

The ID value you are attempting to INSERT needs to already exist in another table. Check to see how `FK_MaterialLot_Company` is defined. Possibly relates to a table called "MaterialLot_Company"?